# Dbeaver connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Is it possible to use Dbeaver to connect to PostgreSQL with SSPI authentication?

I have configured the PostgreSQL (pg_hba.conf) with the following:

> host all all 192.168.100.1/24 sspi

In the Dbeaver, I have added the postgresql driver and also the waffle-jna, screenshot as below

[image]

How do I configure in Dbeaver to make it authenticate with my Kerberos ticket, when I login to any user from my domain, and connect the Postgresql? Can someone please help me?